# Grails project with several inline plugins. How to run tests on the whole app at once?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, clover

I have a project with several inline plugin dependencies.
Is it possible to run tests that cover the whole app (including the plugins) from the project?
I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve publishing the plugins to a repository.

The end goal is to be able to get coverage (clover) on the whole app. 
Right now I can do that using a gradle script which runs test-app on each inline plugin and afterwards in the project and in the end merges the coverage reports.

The problem with this approach is that one of the plugins is compiled many times, because it is a dependency of some of the other plugins and of the project.

Any ideas on how to improve the situation above?